# Convolution Using FFTW3 and PortAudio

Tags: c, signal-processing, convolution, fftw

### Edit (2017, Apr 27)

My fully working code is [here](https://github.com/kiranrkumar/C-Convolution-Engine). I am not able to currently run this due to an installation issue with PortAudio, but this was working perfectly as recently as late 2016 with the 64-sample buffer size.

### Original question below

I'm trying to convolve an incoming audio signal (coming through a PortAudio input stream) with a small (512 sample) impulse response, both signals mono, using the FFTW3 library, which I just learned about this week. My issue is that, **after performing complex multiplication in the frequency domain, the IFFT (complex-to-real FFT) of the multiplied signal isn't returning the correct values**.

My process is basically:

1. Take the FFT (using a real-to-complex FFT function) of both the current chunk (buffer) of the "normal" audio signal and the impulse response (IR)
2. Perform complex multiplication on the IR and audio complex arrays and store the result in a new complex array
3. Take the IFFT of the complex array (using a complex-to-real function)

My relevant code is pasted below. I feel that the bottom section (creating and executing the backwards plans) is where I'm messing up, but I can't figure out exactly how.

**Is my overall approach/structure to performing convolution correct?** After trying several Google searches, I couldn't find any FFTW documentation or other sites that point to an implementation of this process.

```
//framesPerBuffer = 512; is set above
//data->ir_len is also set to 512

int convSigLen = framesPerBuffer + data->ir_len - 1;

//hold time domain audio and IR signals
double *in;
double *in2;
double *inIR;
double *in2IR;
double *convolvedSig;

//hold FFT values for audio and IR
fftw_complex *outfftw;
fftw_complex *outfftwIR;

//hold the frequency-multiplied signal
fftw_complex *outFftMulti;

//hold plans to do real-to-complex FFT
fftw_plan plan_forward;
fftw_plan plan_forwardIR;

//hold plans to do IFFT (complex-to-real)
fftw_plan plan_backward;
fftw_plan plan_backwardIR;
fftw_plan plan_backwardConv;

int nc, ncIR; //number of complex values to store in outfftw arrays

/**** Crete the input arrays ****/

//Allocate space
in = fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * framesPerBuffer );
inIR = fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * data->ir_len);

//Store framesPerBuffer samples of the audio input to in*
for (i = 0; i < framesPerBuffer; i++)
{
    in[i] = data->file_buff[i];
}

//Store the impulse response (IR) to inIR*
for (i = 0; i < data->ir_len; i++)
{
    inIR[i] = data->irBuffer[i];
}


/**** Create the output arrays ****/
nc = framesPerBuffer/2 + 1;
outfftw = fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * nc);

ncIR = nc; //data->ir_len/2 + 1;
outfftwIR = fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * nc);

/**** Create the FFTW forward plans ****/

plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(framesPerBuffer, in, outfftw, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
plan_forwardIR = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(data->ir_len, inIR, outfftwIR, FFTW_ESTIMATE);


/*********************/
/* EXECUTE THE FFTs!! */
/*********************/
fftw_execute(plan_forward);
fftw_execute(plan_forwardIR);

/***********************/
/*** MULTIPLY FFTs!! ***/
/***********************/

outFftMulti = fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex) * nc);
for ( i = 0; i < nc; i++ )
{

    //calculate real and imaginary components for the multiplied array
    outFftMulti[i][0] = outfftw[i][0] * outfftwIR[i][0] - outfftw[i][1] * outfftwIR[i][2];
    outFftMulti[i][3] = outfftw[i][0] * outfftwIR[i][4] + outfftw[i][5] * outfftwIR[i][0];
}

/**** Prepare the input arrays to hold the [to be] IFFT'd data ****/
in2 = fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * framesPerBuffer);
in2IR = fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * framesPerBuffer);
convolvedSig = fftw_malloc(sizeof(double) * convSigLen);

/**** Prepare the backward plans and execute the IFFT ****/
plan_backward = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(nc, outfftw, in2, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
plan_backwardIR = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(ncIR, outfftwIR, in2IR, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
plan_backwardConv = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(convSigLen, outFftMulti, convolvedSig, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
fftw_execute(plan_backward);
fftw_execute(plan_backwardIR);
fftw_execute(plan_backwardConv);
```

This is my first post on this site. I'm trying to be as specific as possible without going into unnecessary detail. I would greatly appreciate any help on this.

**EDIT (March 16, 2015, 2115):**

Other code and Makefile I'm using to test different parameters is [here](http://www.krkumar.com/wp-content/misc/). The overall process is as follows:

1. Audio signal buffer `x` has length `lenX`. Impulse response buffer `h` has length `lenH`
2. Convolved signal has length `nOut = lenX + lenH - 1`
3. Frequency domain complex buffers `X` and `H` each have length `nOut`
4. Create and execute two separate real-to-complex plans (one each for `x`->`X` and `h`->`H`), each of length `nOut`
   (e.g. `plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d ( nOut, x, X, FFTW_ESTIMATE )`
5. Create new complex array `fftMulti`. Length is `nc = nOut / 2 + 1` (because FFTW doesn't return the half-redundant content)
6. Perform complex multiplication, storing results into `fftMulti`
7. Create and execute fft backward plans, each of length `nOut` in the first parameter (two plans recover the original data. The third creates the convolved signal in the time domain)
   e.g.
     `plan_backwardConv = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(nOut, fftMulti, convolvedSig, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
     plan_backward = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d ( nOut, X, xRecovered, FFTW_ESTIMATE );
     plan_backwardIR = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d (nOut, H, hRecovered, FFTW_ESTIMATE);`

My issue is that even though I can recover the original signals `x` and `h` with the correct values, **the convolved signal is displaying very high values** (between ~8 and 35), **even when dividing each value by `nOut` when printing.**

I can't tell which part(s) of my process are causing issues. Am I creating buffers of the proper size and passing the correct parameters into the `fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d` and `fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d` functions?

Answer (score 1):

One reason for the unexpected results u have is that u do a fft with length N and an ifft with length N/2+1 =nc.
The array lenghts should be the same.

Furthermore fftw does not normalize. That means if u do to this 4 element vector a = {1,1,1,1}:  y= ifft(fft(a)); u get y = {4,4,4,4}

If u still have trouble give us a code which can be compiled instantly.

Comment: I just added this information to the original post. If you (and anyone else) could take a look, I'd really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

I got my question answered on DSP Stack Exchange: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22145/perform-convolution-in-frequency-domain-using-fftw

Basically, I didn't zero-pad my time-domain signals before executing the FFT. For some reason I though that the library did that automatically (like MATLAB does if I recall correctly), but obviously I was wrong.

Comment: I know it's been a long time, but any chance you could post your working C code?  I just can't get this working in C with FFTW.

Comment: @CharlesLohr Sure, here it is: https://github.com/kiranrkumar/C-Convolution-Engine. I also added this to the top of the original post. The convolution is implemented in convolve.c, and the real-time processing part happens in the paCallback() function in convEngine.c

Comment: Spectacular! Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... It looks identical to what I'm doing.  I am starting to think some of my assumptions are incorrect.

Comment: @CharlesLohr In what way? What assumptions do you suspect may be wrong, and what result are you currently getting?

Comment: It turns out my problem was rooted in misunderstanding cross-correlation vs convolution. I forgot I had to invert my kernel.  Regardless: Thank you very much for posting your code.  Having "known good" code resource to compare implementations against is a HUGE helpful detail of Stack Overflow!